# How can i style my buttons and text properly?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

How can i style  to make both the buttons at the bottom of the screen and make a little gap between them and how can i make my profile image at the top of the screen and text below it like this image https://www.figma.com/file/BGDDg26x9Cl5AAOA2GGg52/Untitled?t=JCVgnCTjHVkRyhPX-0

i tried to style but something than the profile image and text gets hidden

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native'



const App = () => {

 

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
   
       <View style={styles.userSection}>
            <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
              <Image
                style={styles.image}
                source={('./img.jpg')
                resizeMode="contain"
                overflow="hidden"
              />
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.text}}>Text</Text>
          </View>
        })
      }

      <View style={styles.interacte}>
        <Text style={formbtn}>Button 1</Text>
        <Text style={formbtn}>Button 2</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default App


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  },
  userSection: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 80
  },
  imageContainer: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 80,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    marginRight: -160,
    marginTop: -600
  },
  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: -350,
  },
  interacte: {
    marginTop: 500,
    position: absolute,
  }
});
```

Comment: you can use css's `spacing` and `padding` styles. https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_padding.asp

Comment: Have you tried to give `width` and `height` for top(image, text) and bottom(buttons) containers?

Comment: @ControlAltDel can you test this with my code? with expo

Answer (score 0):

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <View style={{ marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 30 }}>
        <Image
          style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 20 }}
          source={{
            uri: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/919/919851.png',
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Welcome to world</Text>
      <View style={{ marginTop: 300 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            width: 200,
            height: 50,
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            marginBottom: 10,
          }}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
            Sing In
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            width: 200,
            height: 50,
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
            Sing Up
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**output**

[image]

***Hope this will help you!!***